# Perl oneliner match repeating itself

Tags: perl, pcre

I'm trying to read a specific section of a line out of a file with Perl.
The file in question is of the following syntax.

```
# Sets $USER1$ 
$USER1$=/usr/....
# Sets $USER2$ 
#$USER2$=/usr/...
```

My oneliner is simple,

```
perl -ne 'm/^\$USER1\$\s*=\s*(\S*?)\s*$/m; print "$1";' /my/file
```

For some reason I'm getting the extraction for $1 repeated several times over, apparently once for every line in the file after my match occurs. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need a conditional to test for a match, such as `print if /..your regex ../;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing print for every line of the file because print gets called for every line, whether the regex matches or not.  Replace the first `;` with an `&&`.

Comment: Or reset the `$1=""` after each line, but that's less elegant.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Figured it was some kind of logic condition problem.

Comment: @ennuikiller You absolutely CAN easily reset $1. The match variables are reset on any successful match, so match m// (the empty string) to reset them!

Answer (score 2):

From perlre:

NOTE: Failed matches in Perl do not reset the match variables, which makes it easier to write code that tests for a series of more specific cases and remembers the best match.

Try this instead:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1" if m/^\$USER1\$\s*=\s*(\S*?)\s*$/m;' /my/file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat test.txt
# Sets $USER1$ 
$USER1$=/usr/....
# Sets $USER2$ 
#$USER2$=/usr/...

$ perl -nle 'print if /^\$USER1/;' test.txt
$USER1$=/usr/....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
perl -ne '/^.*1?=([\w\W].*)$/;print "$1";' file
```